# Which transistor should I use in my circuit?

Tags: piezo-buzzer

I've made a rudimentary flood alarm (a circuit that rings a buzzer when the water in a reservoir is full) using a 9V battery and a cheap Chinese buzzer that came without a current rating. All I know is that it operates between 6V-12V. There's no power rating on it either, and my multimeter is broken so I can't measure the current myself. There are two parts to the circuit I'm trying to modify it into.

1. Connect a small low-heat capacity resistor in series with the
   battery (to limit current) and put the two open ends of the circuit
   as probes in the water, so that the probes are connected by the
   water, the circuit is completed. I want this part to act as the
   control voltage, applied to the base of the NPN transistor (since I
   want the circuit to close only when the HIGH signal is applied to
   the base).
2. I also want to supply the transistor with 9V which is passed only when the voltage at the base is also applied (i.e., circuit is complete due to the water).

Here's a basic circuit diagram of what I'm trying to create:
[image: Circuit Diagram]

I'm new to this, and have no idea what transistor to use. What should be the value of the resistor? Also, do I need to use any other parts to ensure the proper behavior? Please advise.

Also, is this circuit feasible for long term use? When the battery voltage degrades, will the transistor be able to adapt? I can't use an AC source coupled with a 7809 IC as I want this to be battery operated. Please suggest a better way if need be.

Comment: A mosfet will be more efficent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a bit better way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNCU54.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the probe resistance drops below some tens of M ohms, the beeper will sound. No more than 9uA flows through the probe so electrolysis is minimal. This will work with beepers up to at least a couple hundred mA, above that and Q2 may get too hot while partly on for a TO-92, so you could use a TIP31 or similar TO-220 part (just for Q1).

C1 is to keep the battery voltage more steady as the battery ages (under varying load during the audio frequency beeping cycle), C2 prevents RFI from triggering the beeper. R4 and R2 prevent leakage from triggering the beepr and control the maximum resistance that will trigger the beeper. R1 limits the probe current to prevent electrolysis or overdriving the base of Q1.

Q1 and Q2 are in a Darlington configuration which provides a theoretical current gain of perhaps 50,000, which is tamed somewhat by R2/R4.

Comment: This is amazing! Just to know a bit more, how did you design this circuit? And how did you get the value of the components?

Also, the beeper is continuous in nature. Does that affect the above circuit?

Comment: Nothing here is very critical- mostly just from experience. There's a few hundred gain between Q1 and Q2 so a ratio of R2:R4 in that league makes sense. Time constant for the filter should be > 0.1s and 100n is a common value, so C2. Fresh water resistance between small probes a few inches apart is usually M ohms for our water here, but it's highly dependent on water ionic purity. Really good DI water would be much higher. A more pro method would use capacitance.

Comment: The beeper is continuous in nature. Does that affect the above circuit? Also, since the source is DC, wouldn't the capacitor simply act as an open switch? if not, why not?

Answer (score 3):

Your circuit shows the buzzer on the low side of the transistor, and the transistor as an NPN. This configuration will not work. The buzzer needs to be connected between the collector and the positive terminal of your battery. If you want to put the buzzer on the low side, you need to use a PNP transistor. The transistor itself doesn't really matter, and any regular transistor will do. 2N3904 and 2N2222 are common.

The size of the base resistor in a simple circuit like this is not critical, but there is a problem: the water is in series with the resistor. Performance will vary depending on the conductivity of the water. The amount of current flowing through the buzzer is determined by the amount of current flowing into the base of the transistor. If the water path is resistive, less base current will be able to flow, and therefore less current through the buzzer. The result may be that the buzzer is very quiet or intermittent, which is not good for an alarm system.

The electrodes you use are liable to corrode and become less conductive as well.

Answer (score 2):

Move the buzzer between the battery positive and the npn transistor collector.

But first connect the buzzer to the 9V directly, and use a multimeter with a ammeter mode to measure the current. Use that to figure out the transistor type.

that said, if under 1 Amp, you could just use a 2n2222 or similar common npn transistor and be done with it.